# How to save RAM in a python lottery simulator?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a Python Powerball simulator and I am having problems with it filling up my RAM. How can I make it use less RAM? I am wondering what the RAM is being filled with and how to stop it from filling up, because the program has to run for a long time. Thanks.

```
from __future__ import division
import random
import time

print "welcome to powerball simulator 1, sans power play. run play_lotto(*amount of jackpots to stop at*)"
time.sleep(5)

def lotto_ticket():
    ticket = [random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 35)]
    return ticket

def drawing():
    lotto_drawing = [random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 59), random.randint(1, 35)]
    return lotto_drawing

def check_ticket(list1, list2):
    compare = set(list1) & set(list2)
    return len(compare)

def play_lotto(amount_of_jackpots):
    money = 100
    times_played = 0
    tiers_won = {'tier_1': 0, 'tier_2': 0, 'tier_3': 0, 'tier_4': 0, 'tier_5': 0, 'tier_6': 0, 'tier_7': 0}
    GrandPrizes = 0
    while GrandPrizes != amount_of_jackpots:
        ticket = lotto_ticket()
        draw = drawing()
        money -= 2
        times_played += 1
        total_times_won = tiers_won['tier_1'] + tiers_won['tier_2'] + tiers_won['tier_3'] + tiers_won['tier_4'] + tiers_won['tier_4'] + tiers_won['tier_5'] + tiers_won['tier_6'] + tiers_won['tier_7']
        print 'Money: ',money
        if ticket[5] == draw[5]:
            print 'you win $4, matching powerball'
            money += 4
            tiers_won['tier_1'] +=1
            print 'Times teir one has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_1']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 1 and ticket[5] == draw[5]:
            print 'you win $4, one matching number and matching powerball '
            money += 4
            tiers_won['tier_2'] +=1
            print 'Times teir two has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_2']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 2 and ticket[5] == draw[5]:
            print 'you win $7, two matching numbers and powerball'
            money += 7
            tiers_won['tier_3'] +=1
            print 'Times teir three has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_3']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 3:
            print 'you win $7, three matching numbers'
            money += 7
            tiers_won['tier_4'] +=1
            print 'Times teir four has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_4']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 3 and ticket[5] == drawing[5]:
            print 'you win $100, three matching and powerball'
            money += 7
            tiers_won['tier_5'] +=1
            print 'Times teir five has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_5']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 4:
            print 'you win $100, four matching numbers'
            money += 100
            tiers_won['tier_6'] +=1
            print 'Times teir six has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_6']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 4 and ticket[5] == draw[5]:
            print 'you win $10000, four maching and powerball'
            money += 10000
            tiers_won['tier_7'] +=1
            print 'Times teir seven has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_7']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 5:
            print 'you win $1000000, five matching'
            money += 1000000
            tiers_won['tier_8'] +=1 
            print 'Times teir eight has been won: ',tiers_won['tier_8']
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print tiers_won
        elif check_ticket(ticket, draw) == 5 and ticket[5] == draw[5]:
            print 'you win the jackpot, $250,000,000!'
            money += 2500000
            GrandPrizes += 1
            print 'Times teir nine has been won: ',GrandPrizes
            print 'Total wins: ', tiers_won['tier_1'] + tiers_won['tier_2'] + tiers_won['tier_3'] + tiers_won['tier_4'] + tiers_won['tier_5'] + tiers_won['tier_6'] + tiers_won['tier_7'] + tiers_won['tier_8'] + GarndPrizes
            print 'Lotto entries: ', times_played
            print 'Win percentage: ', total_times_won/times_played
        else:
            print 'you lose'
            print 'win percentage: ',total_times_won/times_played
            print 'Entries: ', times_played
```

Comment: What is the average percentage of RAM used by your program?

Comment: @almanegra It goes up about a megabyte a second, so it starts off at about 60 MB, and eventually just fills up my memory. So, eventually 100%.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: The code seems ok to me. Don't you have anything else?

Comment: What are you using for an output window? That's the only thing I see that increases over time.

Comment: I use IDLE GUI to run the program. @MarkRansom

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything, since it only calls print, then sleep.

Comment: @almanegra No, nothing else.

Comment: @hdante Yes, not until I call the play_lotto function.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code (and leaking memory isn't one of them). In particular, your are not doing a proper lotto draw (you allow a single number to be picked multiple times) and your `elif` tiers are not in the right order.

Comment: I know this isn't Code Review, but... do you recognize that your `drawing()` and `lotto_ticket()` functions are completely redundant?

Comment: What do you mean by that? @AirThomas I am learning and I want some feedback if you have any.

Comment: @smxx: `drawing` and `lotto_ticket` do *the exact same thing*.  There's no reason to have both.

Comment: @jwodder Oh yeah, haha. I didn't realize that until a second ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that your program spews out many lines of output for each iteration of the loop, and you are no doubt running your code from a shell that saves each line of output. You will have to find a different way of running your code or a different place to put your output (like a file).

Comment: Oh yeah, I did forget about that aspect of a lottery drawing, lol. Thanks for the help! I'll probably just make it output it to a file.